# Calling methods

Tags: java, function, methods

I have a project in mind however there are a few basics I need to master before I can proceed. Here's the issue I'm trying to call a function from main in java but I can't get it to compile. I have read the feedback and I went with using a switch to call each function. I always get "error can't find symbol". I've made a few changes here and there trying to get it to run. Once again I feel like I'm lacking something very fundamental and it's preventing me from getting this to work. Any ideas

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Practice {

    static void wagecalc() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input pay per hour:");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b;
        System.out.println("Input hours worked:");
        b = input.nextInt();
        int c;
        System.out.println("Input days worked:");
        c = input.nextInt();

        int gross = a * b * c;
        System.out.println("Your gross pay is:" + gross);

        // Determining tax rate//
        if (gross < 10000) {
            int taxrate = gross * 10 / 100;
            System.out.println("Your tax rate is 10%:/n");

            int total = gross - taxrate;
            System.out.println("Your net pay is:" + total + "/n");
        }

        else if (gross > 10000 || gross <= 30000) {
            int taxrate = gross * 15 / 100;
            System.out.println("Your tax rate is 15%:/n");

            int total = gross - taxrate;
            System.out.println("Your net pay is:" + total + "/n");
        }

        else if (gross >= 30000 || gross <= 70000) {
            int taxrate = gross * 20 / 100;
            System.out.println("Your tax rate is 20%:/n");

            int total = gross - taxrate;
            System.out.println("Your net pay is:" + total + "/n");

        }

        else if (gross > 70000) {
            int taxrate = gross * 25 / 100;
            System.out.println("Your tax rate is 25%:/n");

            int total = gross - taxrate;
            System.out.println("Your net pay is:" + total + "/n");
        }
    }

    static void autocalc() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declaring the variables as an integer//
        int auto;
        int loan;
        int interest;
        int mnydwn;
        int pymnt;
        int year;
        int month = 12;
        int tap;
        int term = year * month;
        int spec;

        System.out.println("Please enter the following information for your car loan:/n");
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of the vehicle you wish to purchase:/n");
        auto = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you wish to put down:/n");
        mnydwn = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate:/n");
        interest = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the term of the loan (years):/n");
        year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Processing......../n");
        System.out.println("Processing............");

        // Calculations//

        loan = auto - mnydwn;
        int intamt = loan * interest;
        tap = loan + intamt;
        pymnt = tap / term;

        // Display//

        System.out.println("Process...Complete./n");
        System.out.println("Car amount:" + auto);
        System.out.println("Loan recieved:" + loan);
        System.out.println("Interest rate:" + interest);

        // if statement for proper output of year//
        if (year == 1) {
            System.out.println("Your monthly payments will be" + pymnt + "for a" + year + "year" + term + "months.");
        } else if (year > 1) {
            System.out.println("Your monthly payments will be" + pymnt + "for" + year + "years" + term + "months.");
        }

        System.out.println("Total amount paid at the end of the term" + tap);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // User input//
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0; // Count for the while loop//

        // Instructions on how to begin interface//

        System.out.println("Hi!/n");
        System.out.println("...Thanks for using D Anomaly's Finance calculator!!/n");
        System.out.println("Please choose one of the following:/n");
        System.out.println(" 1. Wages:/n");
        System.out.println(" 2. Auto Loan:/n");
        // System.out.println(" 3. Home Loan:/n");//
        System.out.println("Choose 1-3");

        int calc = input.nextInt();

        switch (calc) {

        case 1:
            wagecalc();
            break;
        case 2:
            autolcalc();
            break;
        case 3: // homecalc();//
            break;

            if (calc >= 4) {
                System.out.println(" Invalid entry!!!/n");
                System.out.println("Please try again:");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please ask a specific question.  People will be happy to help.

Comment: so what is your question exactly?

Comment: I think the problem is that the code does not compile

Comment: why don't you refer to some books on Java and get started. It will help you to revise many concepts you have forgotten.

Comment: and why are you calculating gross right after receiving it as a method parameter?

Comment: There is no difference between a method and a function in Java. There is only one thing (and it's called a 'method' in official Java terminology in the Java Language Specification, but other people freely use the synonym 'function' when discussing Java programming)

Comment: 1. you can nest methods. 2. There's no reason to create blocks `{...}` inside a method. And 3. if you want to use `Scanner` to [read numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696094/java-accepting-only-numbers-from-user-with-scanner), it's better to start with a small (and working) example and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here, including the following:

1.
`public void wageinformation(int gross)` needs to be declared `static` if you want to call it from `main()`

2.
You are calculating `int gross = a * b * c` right after you have received it as a parameter.

3.
You have (or had in the initial version of this post) several extra braces.

4.
The `deduction` and `total` variables are never declared within the `wageinformation()` method.

I would strongly suggest working through some online Java tutorials if you are looking to improve your skills.